# Regex in Java is not valid (backspace char in brackets)

Tags: java, scala

Why is this regex in Java invalid?

```
(\"[^\"\f\n\v\b]+\")
```

It gives this error(it doesn't like the \b or backspace in the brackets): `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 14
(\"[^\"\f\n\v\b]+\")`

In Ruby for example it works. Regex101 as well https://regex101.com/r/YB24T5/1

Comment: Java is not Ruby.

Comment: all backslashes have to be escaped `\\` -> ´\\\` (sry, without reference)

Comment: `\b` is the java escape for the "backspace character" (so it is a valid escape) , `\\b` is the regex matcher (for word boundary:)..

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, Regex101 has a Java Code Generator. You can find it on the left column of their site.

Your expression was correct, just not escaped properly. For example, all of the backslashes need to be escaped. Here is the output of the Code Generator:

```
String regex = "(\\\"[^\\\"\\f\\n\\v\\b]+\\\")";
String string = "";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```